# How to programatically generate a textual cell displaying the matrix with decorated raised and lowered indices?

Tags: formatting, grid-layouts

This is a basic example of what I want to generate.

```
Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[
  RowBox[{"[", GridBox[{
     {
      RowBox[{
       SuperscriptBox["e", 
        OverscriptBox["1", "_"]], 
       SubscriptBox["\[InvisibleComma]", "1"]}], 
      RowBox[{
       SuperscriptBox["e", 
        OverscriptBox["1", "_"]], 
       SubscriptBox["\[InvisibleComma]", "2"]}]},
     {
      RowBox[{
       SuperscriptBox["e", 
        OverscriptBox["2", "_"]], 
       SubscriptBox["\[InvisibleComma]", "1"]}], 
      RowBox[{
       SuperscriptBox["e", 
        OverscriptBox["2", "_"]], 
       SubscriptBox["\[InvisibleComma]", "2"]}]}
    }], "]"}], TraditionalForm]], "Equation",
 CellChangeTimes->{3.7415291626120205`*^9, {3.7415292581546125`*^9, 3.7415292673520265`*^9}}]
```

I tried the following, with the hope I could simply copy the output and past it into a "DisplayFormual" cell.

```
Module[{element}
 , element[name_][i_, j_] := 
  TemplateApply[
   "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(`n`\), OverscriptBox[\(`a`\), \
\(_\)]]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[InvisibleComma]\), \(`b`\)]\)",  name, "a" -> i, "b" -> j|>];
 Grid[Array[element["e"], {3, 3}]
  ]
 ]
```

It generated the grid the way I want it to look, but it didn't work when I tried to paste it.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is ``Array[Subsuperscript[e, ##] &, {10, 10}]`` sufficient? Then you'd convert it to boxes with `ToBoxes`.

Answer (score 1):

This is **a** way that looks applicable to may of the situations I encounter.  If someone has a better idea.  I would be happy to try it.

```
templateMatrix[template_, n_] := Module[{ebox, i1, i2}
  , ebox[t_][ix_, jx_] := 
   TemplateApply[StringTemplate[t],  ix, "j" -> jx|>];
  CellPrint[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[
      RowBox[{"[", GridBox[Array[ebox[template], {n, n}]], "]"}]
      , TraditionalForm]
     ], "Equation"]]
  ]
templateMatrix["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), OverscriptBox[\(`i`\), \
\(_\)]]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[InvisibleComma]\), \(`j`\)]\)", 3]
templateMatrix["\!\(\*FractionBox[\(\[PartialD]\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\),\
 OverscriptBox[\(`i`\), \(_\)]]\), \
\(\[PartialD]\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(`j`\)]\)]\)", 3]
```